# ASP MVC Set RadioButton From Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, radio-button

I have what should be an easy question for you today.

I have two radio buttons in my view:

```
Sex:
<%=Html.RadioButton("Sex", "Male", true)%> Male
<%=Html.RadioButton("Sex", "Female", true)%> Female
```

I need to select one based on the value returned from my database. The way I am trying to do it now is:

```
ViewData["Sex"] = data.Sex; //Set radio button
```

But that is not working. I have tried every possible combination of isChecked properties. I know that data.Sex is returning either "Male" or "Female". What do I need to do to check the appropriate radio button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the third parameter from the helper:

```
<%= Html.RadioButton("Sex", "Male") %> Male 
<%= Html.RadioButton("Sex", "Female") %> Female
```

And in your controller action:

```
ViewData["Sex"] = "Female";
```

Will check the second radio.

Comment: Thank you sir! I knew it was something easy like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you are storing in the view data, but you could do something like:

```
<%=Html.RadioButton("Sex", "Male", ViewData["Sex"] == "Male")%> Male
<%=Html.RadioButton("Sex", "Female", ViewData["Sex"] == "Female")%> Female
```

Which places a boolean in the 'Checked' overload of the RadioButton method if your view data contains the specified string.